# How do I make Email Field become Unrequired in Joomla K2 Comment

Tags: joomla2.5, k2, emailfield

I have a k2 joomla template, under the articles, there's a comment module with comment form. On the form Email is asterixed and set to required. However I don't want to make email required, just optional. How do I work this out ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method: open /components/com_k2/models/item.php.

Around line 1125, find the following block:

```
$userName = trim($row->userName);
$commentEmail = trim($row->commentEmail);
$commentText = trim($row->commentText);
$commentURL = trim($row->commentURL);
```

Insert before:

```
if ($row->commentEmail==''){
    $row->commentEmail='guest@guest.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the following file in your installation:
`\components\com_k2\models\item.php`

Then remove or comment out the following lines.

```
if (!JMailHelper::isEmailAddress($commentEmail) AND $commentEmail !=  JText::_('K2_ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS'))
        {
            $response->message = JText::_('K2_INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS');
            echo $json->encode($response);
            $mainframe->close();
        }
```